# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, mysql

My asp.net-Mysql application is hosted on windowsserver,when i tried to insert image into mysql table from the admin.aspx page,its displaying the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

But from my VS I can insert image to local mysql server without any error.

When i inserted image from webadmin,it is inserted successfully and displaying image on website.I can update the contents through my admin.aspx,but when i tried to update or insert image,I am getting the error.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Lavande.DBconnect.addimagehome(Byte[] image, String Content, String arabiccontent) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lavande_Asp\Lavande\Lavande\DBconnect.cs:33
   Lavande.abklavande900.button_savehome_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lavande_Asp\Lavande\Lavande\abklavande900.aspx.cs:84
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Following is the code to read the uploaded file:

```
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload_home.PostedFile.FileName);
Byte[] image = WM.ImageSetting("watermarkname", Server.MapPath("upload/") + "logo1.png", path);
DB.addimagehome(image, contentsend, arabiccontent);
```

watermarkclass.

```
public class watermark
{
    public Byte[] ImageSetting(string wmText, string wmImage, string mainImage)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        if (File.Exists(mainImage))
        {

            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(mainImage);

            Graphics graphic;
            if (image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Indexed && image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed && image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed && image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
            {
                // Graphic is not a Indexed (GIF) image
                graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            }
            else
            {
                /* Cannot create a graphics object from an indexed (GIF) image.
                 * So we're going to copy the image into a new bitmap so
                 * we can work with it. */
                Bitmap indexedImage = new Bitmap(image);
                graphic = Graphics.FromImage(indexedImage);

                // Draw the contents of the original bitmap onto the new bitmap.
                graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
                image = indexedImage;
            }
            graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias & SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            //Text Watermark properties
            Font myFont = new Font("segoe script", 17, FontStyle.Bold);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, Color.White));
            SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
            if (wmText != "")
                textSize = graphic.MeasureString(wmText, myFont);

            //Image Watermark
            System.Drawing.Image ig = null;
            if (wmImage != "")
                ig = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(wmImage);

            // Write the text watermark and image watermark across the main image.
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    PointF pointF = new PointF(x, y);
                    PointF pointFm = new PointF(x, y+150);
                    if (wmText != "")
                    {
                        graphic.DrawString(wmText, myFont, brush, pointFm);
                        x += Convert.ToInt32(textSize.Width);
                    }
                    if (wmImage != "")
                    {
                        graphic.DrawImage(ig, pointF);
                        x += Convert.ToInt32(ig.Width);
                    }
                }
                if (wmText != "")
                    y += Convert.ToInt32(textSize.Height);
                if (wmImage != "")
                    y += Convert.ToInt32(ig.Height);

            }

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // save image in memoryStream with it format which get it from GetImageFormat function
                image.Save(memoryStream, GetImageFormat(mainImage));
                imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            graphic.Dispose();
        }


        return imageBytes;


    }

    //function to return Image Format
    ImageFormat GetImageFormat(String path)
    {
        switch (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower())
        {
            case ".bmp": return ImageFormat.Bmp;
            case ".gif": return ImageFormat.Gif;
            case ".jpg": return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            case ".png": return ImageFormat.Png;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: which code is on line number 33? That's where the NullReference Exception comes from...

Comment: this line...MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter("@image", MySqlDbType.LongBlob, image.Length);

Comment: so the passed image is null. Where does the call to addimagehome come from? It might be some security issue...

Comment: yea..the problem is when returning water mark image..

Comment: but..this watermark class is not calling on hosted server..why?

Comment: could it be that the file does not exist on the server? Or more likely: the user your process is running under does not have the right to access the file and then File.Exists returns false. On your local machine the process might run with your rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stack trace and the code it points to, the `image` variable there must be null. The exception is thrown when you try to look at the `Length` property... there is no object there to use to check that property.

The reason it's null is that your `ImageSetting()` function can be summarized like this:

```
Byte[] ImageSetting(...)
{
    Byte[] imageBytes = null;
    if (File.Exists(...) )
    {
        //...
    }
    return imageBytes;
}
```

Obviously, the File.Exists() call fails, and thus you return no image. You likely should have a placeholder image you can load and use instead. Also, you should not use File.Exists() like that in the first place, as the file system is volatile. Instead, put your coding efforts into the exception handler.

Comment: i removed the file.exists condition,now i am getting new error that is:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\4.jpg

Comment: it means this statement is wrong "System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload_home.PostedFile.FileName);",how can i get the right image path

Comment: it was the problem of path from fileupload(we cannot get exact path of client because of security reasons),I used memorystream instead of passing fileupload path and problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

Like I wrote in my comment: your image cannot be retrieved from the server, because your pool identity has not rights to access the directory.

Set the access rights of the directory with the images to everyone, then it might work (for test purpose only).